# Register click and pass it to underlying layer

Tags: javascript, jquery, dailymotion-api

We wanted to track the clicks to some Dailymotion videos which we have added to our site. Unfortunately the Dailymotion javascript API does not provide any event which is called when the user clicks on the video. I thought that maybe I could add a transparent div layer on top of the Dailymotion video layer so that when it was clicked I would register the click and then pass the click to the underlying layer. I know how to do the first part (register the click) but I don´t know how to do the second part (pass the click to the underlying layer). I use jQuery, in case it helps